# Flash Media Server password

Tags: flash, media

Hello
I have flash media server V3 install in my server (windows server 2003 SE) worked OK.
but this is not security when i but rtmp://192.168.0.11/live
stream :alaa
and click connect connected directly
I need to Request user name and password when i click connect 
can you help me

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might be using Flash Media Live Encoder with the Authentication Add-in. Check this [thread](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/847381).